# how to allocate the empty space after setting visibilty with gone in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to draw a sample cell for a recyclerview which contians check box , title and details and an image

My problem is when trying to set the visibility of the details with Gone the title still not taking the space allocated from details view so how i can accomplish this ?

[image]

and the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_55sdp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rBToggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:checked="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrowDown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFreqTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        tools:text="Title "
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/arrowDown"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rBToggle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFreqDetails"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        tools:text="Details "
        android:textColor="#8a898e"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/arrowDown"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rBToggle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFreqTitle"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#c8c7cc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try using setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Comment: It will not work

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a linearLayout inside constraintLayout, inside this Linear you put your two textView

There is a sourceCode

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rBToggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:checked="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrowDown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/arrowDown"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rBToggle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFreqTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"

            tools:text="Title " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFreqDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#8a898e"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:visibility="visible"

            tools:text="Details " />
    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#c8c7cc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I had changed size because i don't have dimen file so you have to update it :) 
Hope this is helpful :)

**UPDATE LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rBToggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:checked="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrowDown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"  />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFreqDetails"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#8a898e"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/arrowDown"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rBToggle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:text="Details " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFreqTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvFreqDetails"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/arrowDown"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rBToggle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Title " />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#c8c7cc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Don't use invisible  
INVISIBLE:

This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

GONE:

This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Comment: The idea behind linear layout is very simple but we are not  utliizing the constraint Layout concept as the linear layout will be nested view

Comment: It is not giving the same shape , you changed the view hierarchy and set fixed height for the views and it is not the right solution

Comment: Hello, I'm based on your own code for height 'android:layout_height="@dimen/_55sdp" ' but i don't have a dimens file so you can change it with your own dimens reference

Answer (score -1):

You can use setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) this will hide the title but its space will be retained.

Comment: Hi @Tavinder I'm trying to hide the details view not the title and invisible will not help as the sapce will rain not utilized

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rBToggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:checked="false" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFreqTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        tools:text="Title "
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFreqDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        tools:text="Details "
        android:textColor="#8a898e"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

</LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrowDown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#c8c7cc" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add explanation to answers along with code, or add comments to the code

Comment: You can you a Linear layout on the top instead of Constrained layout. Just adding android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" will resolve your problem.

Comment: Changing the parent layout is not the proper solution , constraint layout came to replace the other managers